# Open Excel programmatically in "Read Shared" mode

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

My program uses office interop by starting an Excel application (process) and opening an existing workbook.
I must be absolutely certain that all changes written to the workbook by the program can be saved, i.e. something similar to opening a System.IO.File with FileShare.Read or FileShare.None
If file is already opened for writing, my program must be able to detect that.
Anyone knows how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#readOnly) or [`isDirty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=excel-js-preview#isDirty).

With a sample program this may be checked quickly by opening the same workbook in Excel at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! forgot to say that I use c# and office interop, isDirty is not available, however ReadOnly is and fulfills my needs.